# Detecting a Non-Namespaced Event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I'm trying to **detect with jQuery's `on` only events that are not namespaced**.

I tried checking the namespace within the callback of `on` as follows, but it's always undefined:

```
$(".selector").on(
    "click",
    function (e) {
        console.log(e.namespace); // Undefined, not "mynamespace"
    }
);

$(".selector").trigger("click.mynamespace");
```

I've also read that you can append ".$" to the event name to rule out any namespaces, but that only seems to apply within `trigger`, not within `on`. The following runs even if the event is namespaced:

```
$(".selector").on(
    "click.$",
    function (e) {
        // runs even when triggered with a namespace
    }
);
```

I'm not sure where to go from here since when I log the event object, the namespace is nowhere to be found.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to access it through handleObj.

HTML:

```
<div class="selector">
  BOX
</div>
<button onclick="clickWithNamespace()">with ns</button>
<button onclick="clickWithoutNamespace()">without ns</button>
```

JS:

```
$(".selector").on(
    "click.mynamespace",
    manageClick
);
$(".selector").on(
    "click",
    manageClick
);
function manageClick(event) {
   console.log(event.handleObj.namespace);
   $(".selector").text(event.handleObj.namespace);
}

function clickWithNamespace() {
  $(".selector").trigger("click.mynamespace");
}


function clickWithoutNamespace() {
  $(".selector").trigger("click");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j52rmxrs/15/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately that code always says the namespace is "mynamespace" even when it was triggered without the namespace. This is a problem since the goal is to detect when the event is **not** namespaced. In other words, I need it to do what your code does but without the ".mynamespace" in `on`'s first argument. Does that make sense?

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle link with what you would like to achieve. Tomorrow  I ll update the code in the example too. Sorry I am by phone now I took 20 minutes for using stack and jsfiddle by phones